# Cross-Table Criteria Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create an SQL query which returns a Business name. Employees are members of Teams AND of Groups, Teams and Groups are members of Businesses.

I need to select the Business which has employees which are a members of a Team, which has certain attributes as a whole.

How do I go about writing SQL to return the Businesses which have a member to senior member ratio of %? ex Team A has only 20 senior employees out of 100 team members; so it fails and the Business which Team A belongs to should be returned.

I know I need to group Employees together based on their Team, but somehow need to count the Employees who have SENIOR=YES against SENIOR=NO AND return the business they belong to. Ideas?

They are MS Access tables which contain some sensitive information, but you can think of the tables as being set up as follow:
tblBusiness: BID, BName
tblTeam: TID, TName, TBusRef
tblEmployee: EID, EName, ETeamRef, EBusRef, ESenior

I've literally tried all manner of SQL: I've done everything from nested SQL to heavy aggregation to expressions containing count. The closest (I think) I've gotten is:

```
SELECT tblBuisiness.BName FROM tblBuisiness
GROUP BY BName HAVING (
COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT tblEmployee.ETeamRef FROM tblEmployee WHERE ESenior=-1)
/
COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT tblEmployee.ETeamRef FROM tblEmployee)
< 0.5
)
```

Now this one might have syntax errors (was on the clipboard) but I went through it 100x and the closest I got was "cannot have expression in agregate "COUNT()/<0.5" "

If TeamA of Business1 has 20 senior members and 80 regular members, then this query is to return Business1.

Comment: Please show the tables you are working on and an examlpe of the desired output.

Comment: Please provide at least the table structures (columns, sample rows). Preferably also provide at least one example of a failed query to demonstrate the effort you are making.

Comment: Just noticed in your example that your using `ESenior = -1`; is that meant to be `-1` rather then `1`? I would have thought that if an employee is senior then `ESenior` would be 1 otherwise non-seniors would have `ESenior` equal to 0.

Comment: Yes that would make sense, but Microsoft feels it's best to be different. They store checked values as "-1".

Comment: I keep forgetting this is an Access question, d'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    e.EBusRef, 
    Count(e.EID) AS EmpCount, 
    Sum(Abs([ESenior])) AS Senior, 
    [Senior]/([EmpCount]/100) AS [%Senior]
  FROM tblEmployee AS e
  GROUP BY e.EBusRef) q
WHERE q.[%Senior]<=50
```

Comment: Learn something new all the time; had no idea you could give the FROM parameter as another list; thought it was a table or nothing.

Comment: I think this has it solved. It's going to take more tinkering to fit my application, but the method is solid. Thanks a bunch! You'll receive an upvote whenever I can.. =S

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you the percents. You just need to wrap it again to filter on the SeniorPercentage field

```
select 
    B1.BName,
    SeniorPercentage = ((select count(1) from tblEmployee E1 inner join tblTeam T1 where T1.TBusRef = B1.BID and E1.ESenior = 1) / (select count(1) from tblEmployee E2 inner join tblTeam T2 where T2.TBusRef = B1.BID))
From
    tblBusiness B1
```

PS I've not written the joins fully but you can add that in easily.

Comment: That's returning all BNames instead of just the offenders, and is displaying a "0" for percentage or an "N/A". Access also asks me for the "SeniorPercentage" value.. it's doing something but not what I want it to.

EDIT: Just saw what this is doing: this is asking for a percentage, and returns -1 on any Business that hits EXACTLY that percentage. I'll try wrapping it.